# Error 500 en Debian 9

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax, debian-9

Buen día, tengo este fallo con el que amanecí hoy, comento que hace dos días no presentaba ningun tipo de problemas, comento que estoy usando *prepros*, **php**, **jquery**, **mysql**, en **debian 9**, ya reinicie los servicios de estos, pero el error aun sigue, le di permisos totales a todos los ficheros donde están alojados los códigos.
Quisiera alguna solucion para resolver este problema, gracias de antemano

[image: Error mostrado por consola]

Comment: revisaste el log? que es lo que dice en el log? cual es el codigo del archivo que provoca el error??

Comment: @Xerif gracias por contestar, ya solucione el error, se me habia borrado por accidente los dos puntos en uno de los case del switch.